# Is there a shortcut link in GitHub for a repository's latest Pre-release?

Tags: github, links

The unofficial link `https://github.com/[username]/[repository]/releases/latest` automatically redirects into the latest release a repository has.

Is there a similar link that redirects to the latest **pre-release**?
e.g.

- `https://github.com/[username]/[repository]/releases/pre-latest`
- `https://github.com/[username]/[repository]/releases/latest-pre`
- `https://github.com/[username]/[repository]/releases/beta-latest`
- `https://github.com/[username]/[repository]/releases/latest-beta`

[image: Pre-release VS Latest]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Github API? You can fetch all the links from here, so you can give this a try..

`https://api.github.com/repos/[username]/[repository]/releases/latest`

Sample repo: `https://api.github.com/repos/signalapp/Signal-Desktop/releases/latest`

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Please elaborate on why you think this is a correct answer, considering that this site is for questions about using web applications. In other words, it's expected that an answer explains how to do something using the web UI; if that is not possible, answerers should say that. Offering alternatives optional, but when offering using an API it would be clear why it's been suggested are suggesting that. There is a discussion about on [meta]. IIRC it's tagged as [meta-tag:faq].